# Magento 2 redirect to external URL from controller

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, controllers, redirect

I want to redirect to a external URL in my controller but not in the `execute()` function.

This code works fine and the result is a redirect to google:

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('https://www.google.co.uk');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
 )
```

However, this code is not working:

```
public function execute()
{
    $this->testRedirect();
 )

public function testRedirect(){
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('https://www.google.co.uk');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't redirect and leave the page blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the code you are calling another function from execute i.e **testRedirect()** which is returning object **resultRedirect**, but with the object you are not doing anything in execute function. That is why it is showing blank page.

Try this if it works:

```
public function execute()
{
    return $this->testRedirect();
 )
```

Comment: You are a legend!!!! That's 2 days of my life gone... Thank you kindly

Comment: @aman, which class we need to inject for  resultRedirectFactory?

Answer (score 5):

> This code is worked for me

```
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirectFactory
    ) {

        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $redirectLink = 'External Url'; 
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectLink);
                return $resultRedirect;
    }
```